# How to run method once per app start?

Tags: android

Hey I would like to know how I can run a method say, `refreshChannel();` in an `onCreate` in one of my Activities only once, until the application is killed or restarted?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can extend `Application` and run that method in the `onCreate` of your custom application class. This is only run once per application start-up.

For example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Your methods here...
    }
}
```

Note that this should **not be long-running**. If it's going to take some time, do it in an `AsyncTask`.

Last of all, you need to tell Android you have a custom Application class. You do this in your manifest by referencing your application class in the `android:name` attribute of the `application` tag:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity>
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It is best to place this somewhere outside of your Application as this can affect startup times. The other answer, using booleans to determine if it has run, is more performant.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the application class. Then override the onCreate method in the subclass of the Application class. Add a field to the application subclass.

```
public class SubApplication extends Application {
public boolean hasRefreshed;
        @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        hasRefreshed=false;
    }
}
```

Then when you execute on your Activity:

```
SubApplication app = (SubApplication ) context
                    .getApplicationContext();
if(app.hasRefreshed){
//do nothing
}else{
refresh();
app.hasRefreshed=true;
}
```

Last, add this line to your manifest so the system knows to use the subclass.

```
<application
        android:name=".SubApplication "
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity>
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
```